# How to Backup all the folders and files in a USB using UWP C#?

Tags: c#, uwp

In my program, I will need to have a method that are able to backup the whole USB drive to a desired location folder. Just like how we are able to copy the whole folders and files in the USB, but with just a click on my program.

Currently I am only able to backup a single folder with just files in it. Please advise.
Thank you.

```
public async Task CopyFolderAsync(string targetFolder, string desiredName)
{
    StorageFolder externalDevices = KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;
    IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> externalDrives = await externalDevices.GetFoldersAsync();
    StorageFolder rootFolder = externalDrives[0];
    StorageFolder source = await rootFolder.GetFolderAsync(targetFolder);

    StorageFolder destinationFolder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync(desiredName, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

    foreach (var file in await source.GetFilesAsync())
    {
        await file.CopyAsync(destinationFolder, file.Name, NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    }
    await _logManager.GenerateLog("Copying Done");
}
```

Comment: Check the [CommonFileQuery enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.search.commonfilequery?view=winrt-19041) and the [GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefolder.getfilesasync?view=winrt-19041#Windows_Storage_StorageFolder_GetFilesAsync_Windows_Storage_Search_CommonFileQuery_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following code to copy all the folders and files in a certain folder:

```
public static async Task CopyFolderAsync(StorageFolder source, StorageFolder destinationContainer, string desiredName = null)
{
    StorageFolder destinationFolder = null;
    destinationFolder = await destinationContainer.CreateFolderAsync(
        desiredName ?? source.Name, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    foreach (var file in await source.GetFilesAsync())
    {
        await file.CopyAsync(destinationFolder, file.Name, NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    }
    foreach (var folder in await source.GetFoldersAsync())
    {
        await CopyFolderAsync(folder, destinationFolder);
    }
}

public async Task CopyFolderAsync(string targetFolder, string desiredName)
{
……
//Get the rootFolder and destinationFolder
    await CopyFolderAsync(rootFolder, destinationFolder);

}
```